# I want to have a blog text editor in my Nuxt SSR application but it does not appear and gives an error, I am using @tui-nuxt/editor

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, tui, toast-ui-editor

I have a problem with @tui-nuxt/editor

I am following all the steps on this web page

https://github.com/tui-nuxt/editor

but I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know what can I do?

Comment: This is a 2 years old unmantained project, meanwhile have you tried this solution? https://github.com/nhn/toast-ui.vue-editor/issues/24#issuecomment-485347493